# Guide overlay with marquee tool in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to use a guide overlay similar to the crop tool, but with the marquee tool?

I'm trying to crop to a specific aspect ratio and the marquee tool seems to be the only one that can do that.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

With the rectangular marquee tool you can change the style between **Normal, Fixed Ratio and Fixed Size**. The latter two options should achieve what you're after.

Comment: I'm looking for the guides that get shown when doing cropping. Like the "rule of thirds" guide.